# Dictionary Add/Set in one call for performance reasons

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

In a `Dictionary<struct,int>`: is it possible to **Add/Set** in one call?

So is it possible to do the code below in only one lookup per entry?

```
_KeyToPoints = new Dictionary<Key,int>();

foreach ( var entry in billionEntries )
{
    int originalValue;

    // first lookup
    _KeyToPoints.TryGetValue(entry.Key, out originalValue);

    // second lookup
    _KeyToPoints[key] = originalValue + points;    
}
```

This is done in a very tight loop over a huge amount of data, so all performance matters.

Or is there a better suitable data structure?

Comment: I don't believe you can avoid having to index into the dictionary twice (once to get an existing value, and again to set the value), but you can skip setting the originalValue to 0, since TryGetValue will do that for you if the key isn't found.  And, you need to have a check in case TryGetValue returns false.

Comment: Is there an _actual_ performance problem relative to the entire process or are you just _assuming_ that there will be one?  Dictionary lookups are O(1) so there should be very little performance overhead with the look up (and the set for that matter)

Comment: @SlimsGhost You don't need to check the result in this case - if the key did not exist then `_KeyToPoints[key]` would store `0 + points` at that key position.  The code would be the same whether the key existed or not.

Comment: Do you know all of the possible keys?  If so you could pre-initilaize the dictionary with zeros, then you don't have to worry if the key exists or not.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary has AddOrUpdate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665(v=vs.110).aspx - something like that for a plain old Dictionary?

Comment: Hi @DStanley , thanks for your comments.I profiled it and the dictionary lookups are clearly the 'hottest paths' atm. It's a thight loop over a lot of data. Possible keys I don't know until I iterated over the collection :/

Comment: What is the type of your key (the `T` in your generic constraint)?  Is it a primitive type or a custom type with an overridden `GetHashCode`?  Seems odd that dictionary lookups are the bottleneck.  Have you tried grouping the data beforehand using Linq?

Comment: Do you consume _KeyToPoints data at the end, when all adds are done, or you have to keep it up to date between add operations?

Comment: @Dirk Boer One side note is that you don't need to initialize originalValue because TryGetValue will initialize it to its default value, which is 0.

Comment: Tnx SlimsGhost and Ga ber-ber, I've updated the question. @DStanley, this is in a really thight loop over a lot of data, so this is almost everything it does. I made example more clear.

Comment: why are you not trying to simply: _KeyToPoints[key] += points;   ?

Comment: Hi @IvanYuriev, that throw if the key does not exist. Besides it will still do two dictionary lookups under the hood (one for the get, one for the set)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to do this, but it has a downside.  Consider this class:

```
class Ref<T>
{
    public T Value;
}
```

You can use a `Dictionary<K, Ref<int>> dict` and then do this:

```
Ref<int> count;
if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out count))
{
    count = new Ref<int> { Value = 0 };
    dict[key] = count;
}
count.Value += points;
```

The downside is that now you have an additional heap object per entry in your dictionary. Depending on your situation, this may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: Is this faster indeed? You're pretty much having the same operations in place and the very first hit (when adding an item to the dictionary) is even heavier due to creating an object.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst The two approaches would have to be profiled. The question as I interpreted it was simply whether it was possible to do this with only a single dictionary lookup.  I have just explained that, yes, it is possible, and qualitatively characterized the downside.  It may be that profiling reveals this is a horrible approach for performance, but I don't think that invalidates the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Timothy but that creates in this case indeed a lot bigger problems :) i guess i didn't specify my question good enough. If this is really the only way I'll accept it anyway

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own Dictionary.  If all you really need is an optimized setter/getter function for a specific type, then you can make your own Dictionary specialized for the purpose.  The source code for the built-in Dictionary can be found here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0 if you need some reference code to get you thinking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the old [Hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) container :

```
Hashtable map = new Hashtable();
map[key] = value;
```

If the key does not exists, it will create and add it automatically to the map. But you will suffer from the boxing/unboxing if you use a key that is a value type...

Answer (score -2):

Very nasty solution, but it will be faster under the assumption you call the `AddPoints()` method mostly for already existing items in the dictionary.

```
void AddPoints(T key, int points)
{
    try
    {
        _KeyToPoints[key] = _KeyToPoints[key] + points;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        _KeyToPoints[key] = points;
    }
}
```

Throwing and handling exceptions is very expensive (time consuming) and will impact your performance negatively. To avoid this, you can pre-fill the dictionary like this:

```
void PreFillKeys(params T[] keys) // use an IEnumerable<T> if handier
{
    foreach (T key in keys)
    {
        // EITHER THIS:
        if (!_KeyToPoints.ContainsKey(key))
            _KeyToPoints[key] = 0;
        /* OR THIS (faster if you know none of keys was added before)
        try
        {
            _KeyToPoints[key] = 0;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // ignore >> you shouldn't have called 
        }
        */
    }
}
```